# How can I approximate a decimal with two fractions where denominator is less or equal to $d$

Tags: approximation, fractions, continued-fractions, farey-sequences

I was looking for a way to approximate a decimal number with a fraction, whose denominator is less or equal to $d$. Basically, having a decimal $X$, I want to find two fractions such that  $$\frac{a_1}{b_1} < X < \frac{a_2}{b_2}$$ and where $b_1, b_2 \leq  d$

For example if $d=13$, and I want to approximate $X=0.15$, I can approximate it with as $1/7 < X < 2/13$.

The most straightforward idea is to generate all possible fractions $d^2$ and select the most suitable one. But it is too slow and after some investigation I found two potential methods:

- [continuous fractions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction), which actually gives a really good approximation iteratively, but does not takes into account my denominator.
- [farey sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Farey_sequence), which sounds really promising so I will explain what I tried with it.

It looks like this is exactly what I need. The only problem is that it allows to approximate only the number from $[0, 1]$, but in my opinion this is not a problem because I can just map a value $X$ to $[0, 1]$ get a result and scale the result.

There is an algorithm how to generate the next term of the sequence knowing the previous two. The problem is that potentially I have to generate half of the sequence before finding the right one (half because if $X > 0.5$ I am starting from the back, otherwise from the front). It would be super amazing if I can just **skip some of the elements** (being able to generate $n$th element without knowing all $n-1$).

---

My question is: how can I approximate a decimal with two fractions where denominator is less or equal to $d$ in less than $O(d)$ amount of operations? I am looking for the best approximation.

**P.S.** people are suggesting that I eliminated the correct path and continuous fractions are the right tool. I am not sure how can I use it here. For example I want to approximate $0.25$ with $d=113$. My continuous fraction will be just $1/4$ and I have no idea what steps should I use to end up with a correct answers:

$$\frac{28}{113} < 0.25 < \frac{28}{111}$$

Comment: Continued fractions are the right tool.

Comment: Definitely continued fractions.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I updated my question with the reason why I gave up idea of continued fractions.

Comment: I consider $1/4$ as an excellent "approximation." The usual aim is to get good approximations with minimal denominator.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Yes, I have nothing against it, the problem is that $1/4 = 0.25$ and I am looking for such fractions that $\frac{a_1}{b_1} < X < \frac{a_2}{b_2}$. Basically any denominator less or equal to some predefined one.

Comment: I think your problem with $0.25$ is a special one because $1/4$ has a denominator within your range of acceptability.  You can perturb $1/4$ by adding and subtracting $1/d^2$ and use continued fractions.  Since no two fractions with denominator $\leq d$ are within $1/d^2$ of each other, you will get the same neighbors.

Comment: @RossMillikan, if you do that, then $1/4$ will be your first (or second) convergent, and all subsequent convergents will be less than (or greater than) $1/4$. Thus you won't get fractions on either side of it. If you're going to do that perturbation, you've got to maybe do it in both directions, and get two continued fraction expansions.

Comment: @GTonyJacobs: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 1):

To be clear, this is how I understand the question: Given a number $X$ and a bound $b_0$, find the following rational numbers:

- $\frac{a_1}{b_1}=\max\{\frac{a}{b}:\frac{a}{b}<X \text{ and } b\leq
     b_0\}$
- $\frac{a_2}{b_2}=\min\{\frac{a}{b}:\frac{a}{b}>X \text{ and }
     b\leq b_0\}$

You're right that continued fractions aren't helpful in the case where $X$ is a rational number with denominator smaller than $b_0$, as in your example where $X=\frac14$. I'll present a solution for that case only. If $X$ has a large denominator, or is irrational, then I think continued fractions will be more useful for you.

---

Suppose $X=\frac{p}{q}$, with $q<b_0$. Then we know that $b_1$ and $b_2$ must be larger than $b_0-q$. Indeed, if $\frac{a_1}{b_1}<X$ with $b_1\leq b_0-q$, then $\frac{a_1+p}{b_1+q}$ is still less than $X$, and closer than $\frac{a_1}{b_1}$. A similar argument applies for the upper bound.

Consider the set of number numbers $S=\{b_0-q+1, b_0-q+2,\ldots,b_0\}$. These numbers form a complete set of residues modulo $q$. Let $b_1$ be the element of $S$ congruent to $1$, and let $b_2$ be the element of $S$ congruent to $-1$, both modulo $q$. Now let $a_1=p\cdot\frac{b_1-1}{q}$, and let $a_2=p\cdot\frac{b_2+1}{q}$

I claim that these choices of $a_1,b_1,a_2,b_2$ satisfy the stated conditions. Indeed,

$X-\frac{a_1}{b_1} = \frac{p}{q}-\frac{p(b_1-1)}{qb_1} = \frac{1}{qb_1}>0$

and

$\frac{a_2}{b_2}-X = \frac{p(b_2+1)}{qb_2}-\frac{p}{q} = \frac{1}{qb_2}>0$,

so we have the right inequalities, at least.

Proving that they are optimal will take a little more work, but I'm pretty sure this is the solution you want...